# How do I know when Hooks are called and in what order?

Tags: hooks, 8

I want to alter a HTTP header and I am looking for the appropriate hook to use.  I can tell a general time of when some hooks are called but not exactly when.  How do I know exactly when hooks are called, and what hook I should be using to change my header?

edit:  I have managed to change my HTTP header. But something else is adding to my header and that is taking precedent over my header portion.  Is there a way to know where this is coming from?

Comment: The simplest way would probably be to fire up XDebug and put breakpoints in [`ModuleHandler::invoke`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ModuleHandler.php/function/ModuleHandler%3A%3Ainvoke/8) and [`ModuleHandler::invokeAll`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ModuleHandler.php/function/ModuleHandler%3A%3AinvokeAll/8)

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api pages for hooks also show where hooks are invoked from which can be useful in some cases.

Comment: @rooby I am looking on the page and thats where I am finding my hooks, but I dont see a tree or hierarchy of hooks or anything.  They seem to be sorted alphabetically

Comment: You have to search for the hook you are interested in (for example hook_theme), then look for the collapsed fieldset that lists invocations of the hook, then you can follow the links in that fieldset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for an event, not a hook to do this in 8.x

Specifically, you're looking for the RESPONSE event, see `\Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\AnonymousUserResponseSubscriber` for an example. Create a class like that, register it in `yourmodule.services.yml` and then do whatever you want with the $response object.

Comment: How do I create a class like this?  Do you mean I would define the class in my .module file?  or is it in the service.yml file?  I am not sure what all is necessary in the module.services.yml file?

Comment: You need to create the class in the src/ folder of your module, according to the PSR-4 standards, like every other class as well. In services.yml, you need to register it. Look at core.services.yml, search for AnonymousUserResponseSubscriber, then use the definition there as an example.